# Python String Split ^\ is not working

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

Opening my input file in vi editor is like

```
ACT211111011100000000000000000000000606018^\10421040036991^\M/S DOHAR TRADERS^\BD^\167^\050^\000000579300^\000000579300^\
ACT211111011100000000000000000000000606018^\16711010000040^\M/S RAKIB TRADERS^\BD^\167^\050^\000100200386^\000100200386^\
ACT211111011100000000000000000000000606018^\16711010000101^\M-S, OVI ENTERPRISE^\BD^\167^\050^\000000000000^\000000000000^\
ACT211111011100000000000000000000000606018^\16711010000110^\MS. PUSPALATA CONSTRUCTION^\BD^\167^\050^\000000117900^\000000117900^\
```

I want to split the string like

```
ACT211111011100000000000000000000000606018 10421040036991 M/S DOHAR TRADERS BD 167 050 000000579300 000000579300
```

Here i have given the code that i am testing

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
flag220 = 0
f=file("/oasis/ist75/tmp/aa","r").readlines()
linecount=len(f)-1
for i in range(linecount):
        mycmds = []
        index = linecount-i-1
        line = f[index]
        split_line =  line.split()
        print split_line[0]
        if split_line[0].strip() == "ACT211111011100000000000000000000000606018":
            j=index-1
            flag220 = 0
            while j>-1:
                print f[j]
                flag220 = 1
                break
            j=j-1

        if flag220 == 1:
                for j in range (len(split_line)):
                    if split_line[j]=='050':
                        value = split_line[j+1]
                        print value
                        mycmd = './balance.sh ' + value + split_line[1].strip()
                        mycmds.append(mycmd)
                        break
for x in range(len(mycmds)):
    print mycmds[x]
    os.system(mycmds[x])
    mycmds=[]
```

The `print split_line[0]` output is looking like `ACT21111101110000000000000000000000060601810421040036991M/S` which is incorrect. please help me in this regards.

Comment: Where does your code attempt to split on `^\\`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not sure it's a literal `^\\` - I have a suspicion that's vim's way of displaying some control character, but could well be wrong... - but yup - don't see any attempt at splitting anywhere

Comment: I'm sure it's 0x1c, but the code doesn't even try.

Comment: You need to supply the separator to the split method. The only problem is that doing line.split('^\') results in a syntaxerror since the backslash makes the last quotation mark be included in the string, and doing line.split('^\\') also doesn't get me the correct result. To conclude: I'm also curious as to what the answer is..

Comment: i have tried i have also tried split_line = line.split('0x1c'). but still no luck now its coming like ACT21111101110000000000000000000000060601810421040036991M/S DOHAR TRADERSBD167050000000579300000000579300 for  split_line[0] . which should be ACT211111011100000000000000000000000606018

Comment: Here i want to say that i am totally new in python. May be thats why i am missing something.

Comment: Use `print repr(line)` to find out the Python representation of the character.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You were correct on the 0x1c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have finally found the solution. It is like below

```
split_line = line.split('\x1c')
```

Thank you all for your kind co operation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to split on the `^\` characters as well. Regex works well for this:

```
import re
re.split('(\^\\|\s)', line)
```

That said, if that `\^` isn't literal (which kind of looks to be the case) then you'll need to split on that instead.

Comment: thanks now the output of print split_line[0] is coming like ACT21111101110000000000000000000000060601810421040036991M/S DOHAR TRADERSBD167050000000579300000000579300. which should be ACT211111011100000000000000000000000606018

Comment: i have also tried split_line = line.split('0x1c') that is same

Comment: You need to find out what that character is that you're seeing in your editor. Alternatively if it's only occurring after a fixed length then you can build a regex on that.